# Передача таблицы в метод Entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть класс моей базы KISATPEntities. И три поля типа DbSet - мои таблицы. Я хочу написать универсальный метод удаления записи из таблицы. В метод буду передавать id записи и непосредственно таблицу, запись в которой нужно удалить. Совсем уже не знаю как это реализовать и как передать эту таблицу в качестве параметра, перепробовал кучу вариантов.

Comment: EF 7.x, и да, wpf тут ни при чем

Comment: Entity Framework Core 7

Comment: [DbContext.Remove Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.remove?view=efcore-7.0). Можно просто `db.Remove(entity);`

Comment: Я понимаю, что мы можем через встроенный метод ремув удалять записи. Но так нужно будет писать отдельный подход к каждой таблице. Хотелось бы просто передавать в метод таблицу и поле-идентификатор и удалять запись. (ее можно через Find()). Ну может мы недопонимаем друг друга яж дилетантище пока что

Comment: Дело вот в чём. Откуда взялся DbSet, который передаётся в метод Delete? Не следует оперировать этим классом. – 
Alexander Petrov
 2 минуты назад Понял, а возможно ли вообще осуществить то, что я задумал?

Comment: Ещё раз: `db.Remove`. Где тут упоминание `table` или `DbSet`? / Это метод самого _контекста_.

Comment: `int id` - это айдишник _чего_? Какого класса/типа? Вернее, какой сущности?

Comment: это поле-идентификатор таблицы, которую я хочу передать в метод

Comment: может мы можем в дисе это обсудить? не хочу показаться наглым, но если есть время желание и возможность

Comment: ну вот такой вот сущности public partial class Professions
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string profession { get; set; }
        public decimal salary { get; set; }
    }
например

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу предложить следующее.

```
public void Delete<T>(T entity) where T : class
{
    using var db = new KISATPEntities();
    db.Remove(entity);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Что именно вы пытаетесь удалить, вам должно быть известно. Например, это тип `Profession`. У вас есть айдишник. Создаём экземпляр этой сущности и передаём в наш метод.

```
var profession = new Profession { Id = id };
Delete(profession);
```

При этом перед удалением не нужно предварительно запрашивать сущность из БД.

---

Comment: нашел в интернетах решение, ваше не подошло, т.к. метод ремув - метод применим не к контексту, а к модели окнтекста, но вы мне показали как пользоваться. Прошу прощения за ваши нервы и свою глупость

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Delete<TEntity>(TEntity entity) 
    where TEntity : class
{
    // Настройки контекста
    SampleContext context = new SampleContext();
    context.Database.Log = (s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s));

    context.Entry<TEntity>(entity).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    context.SaveChanges();
}
Profession prof = new Profession(){id = 5};
Delete(prof);
```

Comment: Это **не** EF Core!

Comment: Я несколько раз спрашивал: какая именно версия EF используется? Вы пишете, что EF Core 7, но в ответе используете EF 6 (без суффикса Core).

Comment: Понял, я - дурак